# How to make the style copied from the source xlsx file the same as the style of the target xlsx file？

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

erryone.this is the problem I encountered.
Splitting multiple sheet pages in xlsx into multiple xlsx files containing only one sheet page using POI-OOXML 4.1.2 results in inconsistent styles when copying. How to solve this problem?
this is source xlsx file:
[source pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMzyy.png)
this is target xlsx file:
[target pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi2RK.png)
The difference between the two pictures is that the filling colors are different. What is the expected filling color is source pic's.The fill color for the first and second rows of the source pic is RGB HEX F4B7BE, but the target pic's RGB HEX is C6E0B4. They are different.
this is my copy cellStyle code :

```
       ...
            targetStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) targetWorkbook.createCellStyle();

            targetStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceStyle);

            copyFont(((XSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFont(), ((XSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).getFont(), targetStyle);
```

What is the expected filling color is source pic's.
i tried to copy the style using the following code：

```
            targetStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceStyle);

            XSSFColor sourceFillForegroundXSSFColor = ((XSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFillForegroundXSSFColor();
            XSSFColor sourceFillBackgroundXSSFColor = ((XSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFillBackgroundXSSFColor();
            ((XSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).setFillForegroundColor(sourceFillForegroundXSSFColor);
            ((XSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).setFillBackgroundColor(sourceFillBackgroundXSSFColor);
            targetStyle.setFillPattern(sourceStyle.getFillPattern());
```

it didn't work.
here is all my code as follow :
`

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExcelSplitterUtil {

private final static Map<Integer, Map<Integer, CellStyle>> styleCacheLocal = new HashMap<>();

private final static String excelFileType = ".xlsx";

public static void main(String[] args) {
String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\15206\\Desktop\\excel_sheet\\test3\\xlsx文件样式测试1.xlsx";
String outputFolderPath = "C:\\Users\\15206\\Desktop\\excel_sheet\\test3\\target\\";
excelSplitter(inputFilePath, outputFolderPath);
}

public static void excelSplitter(String inputFilePath, String outputFolderPath) {


try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)) {
    Workbook sourceWorkbook;
    if (inputFilePath.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
        sourceWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    } else if (inputFilePath.endsWith(".xls")) {
        sourceWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sourceWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++) {
        Workbook targetWorkbook = null;
        String sheetName = sourceWorkbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getSheetName();

        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(excelFileType)) {
            if (excelFileType.equals(".xlsx")) {
                targetWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            } else if (excelFileType.equals(".xls")) {
                targetWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            } else {
                //log.error("Unsupported Excel file format: {}", excelFileType);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            //throw new BizRuntimeException("ExcelFileType cannot be empty!");
        }
        //}

        Sheet sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
        Sheet targetSheet = targetWorkbook.createSheet(sourceSheet.getSheetName());

        copySheet(sourceSheet, targetSheet, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkbook, excelFileType);

        String outputFilePath = outputFolderPath + sheetName + excelFileType;

        List<String> uploadPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        uploadPaths.add(outputFilePath);

        if (!new File(outputFilePath).exists()) {
            String tempDir = outputFilePath.substring(0, outputFilePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            new File(tempDir).mkdirs();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath)) {
            targetWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);
        }
        targetWorkbook.close();
    }

    sourceWorkbook.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

} catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {

}
}

private static void copySheet(Sheet sourceSheet, Sheet targetSheet, Workbook sourceWorkbook, Workbook targetWorkbook, String excelFileType) {

int totalRowNum = sourceSheet.getLastRowNum() - sourceSheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1;
System.out.println("totalRowNum--------------------" + totalRowNum);

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < totalRowNum; rowIndex++) {
    Row sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    Row targetRow = targetSheet.createRow(rowIndex);

    if (sourceRow != null) {
        // 设置行宽
        float sourceRowHeightInPoints = sourceRow.getHeightInPoints();
        targetRow.setHeightInPoints(sourceRowHeightInPoints);

        int cellNum = sourceRow.getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("cellNum-----------{}----" + cellNum);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); colIndex++) {
            Cell sourceCell = sourceRow.getCell(colIndex);
            Cell targetCell = targetRow.createCell(colIndex);

            if (sourceCell != null) {
                // 处理不同数据类型的赋值
                setCellValue(targetCell, sourceCell);

                // 设置列宽
                int columnWidth = sourceSheet.getColumnWidth(colIndex);
                // 从第colIndex列开始，该列的宽度是 columnWidth
                targetSheet.setColumnWidth(colIndex, columnWidth);

                //复制样式
                copyCellStyle(sourceCell, targetCell, targetSheet, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkbook, excelFileType);
            }

        }
    }
}
}

private static void copyCellStyle(Cell sourceCell, Cell targetCell, Sheet targetSheet,
                              Workbook sourceWorkbook, Workbook targetWorkbook, String excelFileType) {
CellStyle sourceStyle = sourceCell.getCellStyle();
CellStyle targetStyle = getOrCreateTargetStyle(sourceStyle, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkbook, excelFileType);

// 将新样式应用于目标单元格
targetCell.setCellStyle(targetStyle);

// 合并单元格信息
CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = findMergedRegion(sourceCell, sourceCell.getSheet());
if (mergedRegion != null && !isMergedRegionOverlapping(mergedRegion, targetSheet)) {
    targetCell.getSheet().addMergedRegion(mergedRegion);
}
}

private static CellStyle getOrCreateTargetStyle(CellStyle sourceStyle, Workbook sourceWorkbook, Workbook targetWorkbook, String excelFileType) {
int sourceStyleIndex = sourceStyle.getIndex();

if (styleCacheLocal.containsKey(sourceStyleIndex)) {
    Map<Integer, CellStyle> workbookStyles = styleCacheLocal.get(sourceStyleIndex);
    return workbookStyles.computeIfAbsent(System.identityHashCode(targetWorkbook), key -> createAndCacheStyle(sourceStyle, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkbook, excelFileType));
} else {
    return createAndCacheStyle(sourceStyle, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkbook, excelFileType);
}
}

private static CellStyle createAndCacheStyle(CellStyle sourceStyle, Workbook sourceWorkbook, Workbook targetWorkbook, String excelFileType) {
CellStyle targetStyle = null;
if (excelFileType.equals(".xlsx") && sourceStyle instanceof XSSFCellStyle) {
    // 源excel 是 xlsx, 目标是xlsx
    targetStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) targetWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    // 复制基本的样式属性
    targetStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceStyle);

    //复制字体
    copyFont(((XSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFont(), ((XSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).getFont(), targetStyle);
} else if (excelFileType.equals(".xlsx") && sourceStyle instanceof HSSFCellStyle) {
    // 源excel 是 xls, 目标是xlsx
    targetStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) targetWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    // 复制其他样式属性
    manualCloneStyle(targetStyle, sourceStyle);

    //复制字体
    HSSFFont sourceFont = (HSSFFont) sourceWorkbook.getFontAt(sourceStyle.getFontIndexAsInt());
    copyFont(sourceFont, ((XSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).getFont(), targetStyle);
} else if (excelFileType.equals(".xls") && sourceStyle instanceof XSSFCellStyle) {
    // 源excel 是 xlsx, 目标是xls
    targetStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) targetWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    // 手动复制不兼容样式
    manualCloneStyle(targetStyle, sourceStyle);

    //复制字体
    copyFont(((XSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFont(), ((HSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).getFont(targetWorkbook), targetStyle);

} else if (excelFileType.equals(".xls") && sourceStyle instanceof HSSFCellStyle) {
    // 源excel 是 xls, 目标是xls
    targetStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) targetWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    // 复制基本的样式属性
    targetStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceStyle);

    //复制字体
    copyFont(((HSSFCellStyle) sourceStyle).getFont(sourceWorkbook), ((HSSFCellStyle) targetStyle).getFont(targetWorkbook), targetStyle);
} else {
    System.out.println("文件类型excelFileType不匹配");
    return null;
}

Map<Integer, CellStyle> workbookStyles = new HashMap<>();
workbookStyles.put(System.identityHashCode(targetWorkbook), targetStyle);
styleCacheLocal.put(Integer.valueOf(sourceStyle.getIndex()), workbookStyles);

return targetStyle;
}

private static void manualCloneStyle(CellStyle targetStyle, CellStyle sourceStyle) {
targetStyle.setAlignment(sourceStyle.getAlignment());
targetStyle.setVerticalAlignment(sourceStyle.getVerticalAlignment());
targetStyle.setWrapText(sourceStyle.getWrapText());
targetStyle.setDataFormat(sourceStyle.getDataFormat());
targetStyle.setFillForegroundColor(sourceStyle.getFillForegroundColor());
targetStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(sourceStyle.getFillBackgroundColor());
targetStyle.setFillPattern(sourceStyle.getFillPattern());
targetStyle.setHidden(sourceStyle.getHidden());
targetStyle.setIndention(sourceStyle.getIndention());
targetStyle.setLocked(sourceStyle.getLocked());
targetStyle.setRotation(sourceStyle.getRotation());
targetStyle.setBorderBottom(sourceStyle.getBorderBottom());
targetStyle.setBorderLeft(sourceStyle.getBorderLeft());
targetStyle.setBorderRight(sourceStyle.getBorderRight());
targetStyle.setBorderTop(sourceStyle.getBorderTop());
targetStyle.setTopBorderColor(sourceStyle.getTopBorderColor());
targetStyle.setBottomBorderColor(sourceStyle.getBottomBorderColor());
targetStyle.setLeftBorderColor(sourceStyle.getLeftBorderColor());
targetStyle.setQuotePrefixed(sourceStyle.getQuotePrefixed());
targetStyle.setShrinkToFit(sourceStyle.getShrinkToFit());
}

private static void copyFont(Font sourceFont, Font targetFont, CellStyle cellStyle) {
targetFont.setFontName(sourceFont.getFontName());
targetFont.setFontHeightInPoints(sourceFont.getFontHeightInPoints());
targetFont.setBold(sourceFont.getBold());
targetFont.setItalic(sourceFont.getItalic());

if (targetFont instanceof XSSFFont) {
    if (sourceFont instanceof XSSFFont) {
        ((XSSFFont) targetFont).setColor(((XSSFFont) sourceFont).getXSSFColor());
    } else if (sourceFont instanceof HSSFFont) {
        ((XSSFFont) targetFont).setColor(sourceFont.getColor());
    }
} else {
    if (sourceFont instanceof XSSFFont) {
        ((HSSFFont) targetFont).setColor(sourceFont.getColor());
    } else if (sourceFont instanceof HSSFFont) {
        ((HSSFFont) targetFont).setColor(sourceFont.getColor());
    }
}
// 设置新字体到新样式
cellStyle.setFont(targetFont);
}

private static void setCellValue(Cell targetCell, Cell sourceCell) {
switch (sourceCell.getCellType()) {
    case STRING:
        targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getStringCellValue());
        break;
    case NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(sourceCell)) {
            targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
            targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        break;
    case BOOLEAN:
        targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case FORMULA:
        targetCell.setCellFormula(sourceCell.getCellFormula());
        break;
    default:
        targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.toString());
        break;
}
}

private static boolean isMergedRegionOverlapping(CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion, Sheet targetSheet) {
for (int i = 0; i < targetSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
    CellRangeAddress existingMergedRegion = targetSheet.getMergedRegion(i);
    if (existingMergedRegion.intersects(newMergedRegion)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

private static CellRangeAddress findMergedRegion(Cell cell, Sheet sourceSheet) {
for (int i = 0; i < sourceSheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
    CellRangeAddress merged = sourceSheet.getMergedRegion(i);
    if (merged.isInRange(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex())) {
        return merged;
    }
}
return null;
}
}
```

`and here is my pom.xml as follow :`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- excel tool -->
    <!--xls(03)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--xlsx(07)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
        <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

`
Just now, I tried to set the style in Excel and save it as the source file, and then handed the file to the program to split and copy the style. The result was that the style of the target file is inconsistent with that of the source file. How should I adjust it to be the same?Here are screenshots of my source and target files.
[source src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qsj5.png); [target src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqubd.png)

I feel like it's a POI bug!

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Are both screenshots from same application? What application? Seems not Excel. WPS Office != Excel! Maybe the fill colors are theme colors and WPS Office interprets theme colors different than Excel. Apache POI creates Excel file contents. So the `targetWorkbook` is an Excel workbook using Excel theme colors rather than WPS Office  workbook theme colors.

Comment: @Axel Richter
 Thanks for your reply. Screenshot of the source pic was manually set, and screenshot of the target pic was from application. Here is my code :
`targetStyle.cloneStyleFrom(sourceStyle)`

The program is too long to be written in the comments section.

I know WPS Office != Excel,I have opened this file using Excel and found that it is still different. I plan to use Excel to set the style and then use the program to copy the style.

Comment: @Axel Richter  Hi, i added the program and its corresponding dependencies at the end.
Just now, I tried to set the style in Excel and save it as the source file, and then handed the file to the program to split and copy the style. The result was that the style of the target file is inconsistent with that of the source file. How should I adjust it to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

The difference may be due to the fill colors being theme colors and one spreadsheet application interpreting the theme colors differently than the other.

But also when in same application the problem might be different theme color interpretation. Try to choose a different standard color theme in your target files.
On the **Page Layout** tab in Excel or the **Design** tab in Word, click **Colors**, and pick the color set you want. Default should be "Office". Try "Office 2013 - 2022" or "Office 2007 - 2010". Are the colors now the correct ones?

Using the binary `*.xls` format (`HSSF`) there are color differences when `source.xlsx` was created using an Excel version greater than 2007 and compatibility check warnings was thrown while saving. This is due to the fact that Apache POI creates `*.xls` files in a format which corresponds old Excel versions before compatibility check was introduced.

But maybe there is something else problematic in your extensive code. Or there was bugs in the used old Apache POI version 4.1.2.

Using current Apache POI 5.2.5 the same functionality can be reached using following small code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

public class ExcelSplitterUtil  {

 public static void excelSplitter(String inputFilePath, String outputFolderPath) {
  try ( Workbook sourceWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)); ) {

   for (Sheet sourceSheet : sourceWorkbook) {

    String sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();

    Workbook targetWorkbook = null;
    String suffix = "";
    if (sourceWorkbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
     targetWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
     suffix = ".xlsx";  
    } else if (sourceWorkbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
     targetWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();          
     suffix = ".xls";   
    }

    Sheet targetSheet = targetWorkbook.createSheet(sourceSheetName);

    CellCopyPolicy cellCopyPolicy= new CellCopyPolicy();
    CellCopyContext cellCopyContext = new CellCopyContext();
  
    for (Row sourceRow : sourceSheet) {
     Row targetRow = targetSheet.createRow(sourceRow.getRowNum());
     for (Cell sourceCell : sourceRow) {
      Cell targetCell =  targetRow.createCell(sourceCell.getColumnIndex());
      CellUtil.copyCell(sourceCell, targetCell, cellCopyPolicy, cellCopyContext);
     }
    }

    String outputFilePath = outputFolderPath + sourceSheetName + suffix;
   
    try ( FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath) ) {
     targetWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    }
    targetWorkbook.close();
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
  
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //String inputFilePath = "./source.xls"; //file must exist
  String inputFilePath = "./source.xlsx"; //file must exist
  String outputFolderPath = "./target/"; //path must exist
  excelSplitter(inputFilePath, outputFolderPath);
 }
}
```

The solution is the usage of [CellUtil.copyCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#copyCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyContext-) which internally does the same as your extensive code. Maybe try this after upgrading to Apache POI 5.2.5 ?

---

Maybe try another approach to split a workbook into sheets without copying the sheets into a new workbook.

**Approach:**

- Get a list of all sheet names of source workbook.
- Then for each sheet name:

  - Open the source workbook.
  - Remove all sheets which not have the name of that sheet name.
  - Write that workbook using sheet name as file name.

This will preserve all workbook settings, including themes.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExcelSplitterUtilV2  {

 public static void excelSplitter(String inputFilePath, String outputFolderPath) {
  List<String> allSourceSheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  String suffix = "";

  try ( Workbook sourceWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)); ) {
   for (Sheet sourceSheet : sourceWorkbook) {
    allSourceSheetNames.add(sourceSheet.getSheetName());
   }   
   if (sourceWorkbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    suffix = ".xlsx";  
   } else if (sourceWorkbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    suffix = ".xls";   
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  for (String sourceSheetName : allSourceSheetNames) {
       
   String outputFilePath = outputFolderPath + sourceSheetName + suffix;   

   try ( Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)); 
         FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath) ) {
             
    for (int s = workbook.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; s >= 0; s--) {
     if (!sourceSheetName.equals(workbook.getSheetName(s))) {
      workbook.removeSheetAt(s); 
     }
    }
     
    workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
  
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //String inputFilePath = "./source.xls"; //file must exist
  String inputFilePath = "./source.xlsx"; //file must exist
  String outputFolderPath = "./target/"; //path must exist
  excelSplitter(inputFilePath, outputFolderPath);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I plan to try Beijing time tonight

Comment: Great, following your prompt, I found that the theme of the source Excel file is Office 2013-2022, while the theme of the target Excel file is Office. When I adjusted the theme of the target Excel file to Office 2013-2022, the colors now are the correct ones. The approach is great. I really want to treat you to a cup of coffee. Thank you